# Paypal button manager doesn't accept decimal amount

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have this part in my view, it is like a catalog that shows the items that user can buy:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.genero.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeArtista)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Preco)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Play", "", new { path = item.path }) |
            @if (item.Preco > 0)
            {
                string price = item.Preco.ToString("0.00");
                var payPalBtn = PayPal.ButtonManager.AddToCartButton.Create(
                       business: "pedrro2-facilitator@hotmail.com",
                       itemName: item.Nome,
                       amount: price
                       );


              HtmlString payPalBtnHtml = new HtmlString(payPalBtn.WebSiteCode);

             @Html.ActionLink("| Adicionar ao carrinho", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = item.MusicaId },"")
            }else{
            <button type="button" class="addmusic" data-id="@item.MusicaId">Add</button>
            }

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In my model, the variable `Preco` is **decimal**, but the `amount` parameter for `PayPal.ButtonManager.AddToCartButton.Create` method must be a **string**, what is the best way to convert this variable `Preco` to a string?

I tried to convert using this line of code:

```
string price = item.Preco.ToString("0.00");
```

But it's not working, this exception is displayed:

> PayPal.ButtonManager.ButtonManagerException: Invalid Argument - Amount is not valid

Comment: Can you add the rendered html to the question?

Comment: The html don't is rendered, the exception is displayed while the page load @ekad

Comment: On the debug, the value of price is "2,00" and on database is saved as "2,00" too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding this:

```
string price = item.Preco.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the value `2,00` because the computer where you run the code is using Portuguese culture or any culture that uses `,` as the decimal separator. You can get the string value with `.` as the decimal separator by using `en-US` culture when converting the decimal value to string

```
string price = item.Preco.ToString("0.00", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```